# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_12_input to have shape (5793993, 7) but got array with shape (7, 1)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
 keras.layers.LSTM(150, activation='sigmoid',return_sequences=True,input_shape=(X_train.shape)),
 keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
```

above is the first layer
(5793993, 7, 1) this is the input shape

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_12_input to have shape (5793993, 7) but got array with shape (7, 1)

What is fix for this tensorflow bug

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't include the number of samples for `input_shape`. Use this instead:

```
input_shape=(X_train.shape[1:])
```

I'm also fairly certain that your input should have shape `(n_samples, 1, 7)` to have it run.

Comment: No, `(n_samples, 7, 1)` is correct for LSTM, the other way around would make recurrent layers useless.

Comment: this happens when I use colab. Same code works properly in jupyter